# PostgreSQL why is passing parameters through functions 3 times faster than temporary tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

In PostgreSQL I created a set of 8 table based functions originally but the query was taking 7 seconds, so I recreated as 8 temporary tables, the query is very heavy on `leads / lags` and using sub queries to find the next code that isn't `NULL` etc. Along with an unpivot on a large dataset.

Apart from joins this is the only processing required, I'm wondering why what is the exact same code runs so much faster when passing parameters through functions.

The original reason I did this was because using the functions meant the processing had to be done twice as the functions would refer to each other

To give some idea of the structure it goes:

```
cycle_1_load
cycle_2_dump
cycle_3_unpivot
cycle_4_truck_union
cycle_5_truck_convert
cycle_6_excav_union
cycle_7_excav_convert
cycle_8_add_states
```

using the temp tables I thought this would speed up the query greatly but it actually made it 3x as slow. Is there some performance hit with temp tables in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Temp tables usually don't solve performance problems. They actually increase the work the database has to do. But without seeing your code it's impossible to answer.

Comment: Right. And I don't understand what you mean by "parameters passed through functions".

Comment: Each function builds from the previous by passing WHERE site_id = $1 AND date BETWEEN $2 AND $3, so the queries can limit the data being processed inside each function. Thanks a_horse_with_no_name, that's all I'm looking for, is if it's best to stay away from temp tables, performance is my main concern. I'm replacing a query on production software so I can't share the code sorry, I've taken the original mess of a query from 3.5 minutes down to 9 seconds but I was hoping to get it down to 1-2 seconds.